# Reactjs shows the message in console but not in UI

Tags: reactjs

I am new in Reactjs and I met an issue trying to update the DOM dynamically. In the code below the console shows the "currentQuestion.theQuestion" but it does not appear in UI.

```
function nextQuestionFunction () {
      let index = questions.indexOf(currentQuestion);
      index += 1;
      //mallon thelei setState gia na doulepsei
      currentQuestion = questions[index];
      console.log(currentQuestion.theQuestion);
    }

    return ( 
      <div>
          <p>{currentQuestion.theQuestion}</p>
          <ul style={{listStyleType : 'none'}}>{answers}</ul>
          <button onClick={() => nextQuestionFunction()}>Next Question</button>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: If you mutate a local variable inside a component this will not affect the rendering cycle of a component. You need to store desired data in the state and update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store data to state to use on return function, not local variable cuz local variable only used on block scope function.

```
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = React.useState('');

    function nextQuestionFunction () {
      let index = questions.indexOf(currentQuestion);
      index += 1;
      currentQuestion = questions[index];
      setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion.theQuestion);
    }

    return ( 
      <div>
          <p>{currentQuestion}</p>
          <ul style={{listStyleType : 'none'}}>{answers}</ul>
          <button onClick={() => nextQuestionFunction()}>Next Question</button>
      </div>
    );
```